# Can't save data from HTML form to database Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save data entered in this form (below) into a database:

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TODO</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <form id='add-task' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task-name" placeholder="task name">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task-desc" placeholder="description">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deadline" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </br></br>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if I poorly formatted the code or if I'm using the wrong HTML. Is it possible to do this using HTML or should I just use a ModelForm?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .models import Task

def home(request):

     # checks if user is logged in so that it can display task creation page
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'user': request.user})

    # add new task --->  ALL THE CODE BELOW 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = str(request.POST['task-name'])
        desc = str(request.POST['task-desc'])
        deadline = request.POST['deadline']
    
        task = Task(task_name=name, task_desc=desc, task_deadline=deadline)

        task.save()
        

    #messages.success(request, "You've added a task.")
        
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

Comment: If the user is authenticated you never check the request method, so the second `if` never runs

Comment: @mousetail I appreciate the help. That makes perfect sense, it seems that the return statement ends the function as soon as the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your code as it is running:

```
def home(request):

 # checks if user is logged in so that it can display task creation page
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
      if request.method == 'POST':
           name = str(request.POST['task-name'])
           desc = str(request.POST['task-desc'])
           deadline = request.POST['deadline']
           task = Task(task_name=name, task_desc=desc, task_deadline=deadline)
           task.save()

       return render(request, 'home.html', {'user': request.user})
    else:
       return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

But you don't need to pass in `user` as context. This is available anyway.

So you could just do:

```
def home(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
        name = str(request.POST['task-name'])
        desc = str(request.POST['task-desc'])
        deadline = request.POST['deadline']
        task = Task(task_name=name, task_desc=desc, task_deadline=deadline)
        task.save()

  return render(request, 'home.html')
```

And `request.user` will still be available as `{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}` in your template.